Togglz: How to use SpringProfileActivationStrategy
I'm new to Togglz and there is not much documentation on this problem, nor have I found a solution from searching the web and Stack overflow. (I found one person asking the same question but he wasn't given a solution). I'm trying to write a POC using Togglz.
I have an existing Spring boot 2 project and am using Togglz 3.3.3.
I have defined some feature flags in an enum. One of these feature flags (FEATURE_TWO), I want to be active only if the current spring profile is "dev". This is the enum:
public enum TogglzFeatureFlags implements Feature {

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("First feature")
    FEATURE_ONE,

    @Label("Second feature")
    @DefaultActivationStrategy(id = SpringProfileActivationStrategy.ID, parameters = {
            @ActivationParameter(name = SpringProfileActivationStrategy.PARAM_PROFILES, value = "dev")
    })
    FEATURE_TWO,

    @Label("Third feature")
    FEATURE_THREE;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }

}

When I start up the application in dev and go to the Togglz console, it seems to be recognising the activation strategy (It reads Spring profile: dev) but that feature remains red and disabled, even when in the dev profile.
Togglz console
Does anyone know a fix for this please?
Thanks in advance.

Togglz distinguishes between enabled and activated features. You need to @EnabledByDefault the second feature too, and its active status will be dynamically interpreted by the Spring profile.
